# How to plot the dielectric function calculated with Yambo?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, optical-properties, yambo

I want to calculate the optical properties using Yambo.
I used Quantum ESPRESSO 7.0 with Yambo 5.1.0, but I'm facing an issue. When I generate the dielectric function (o.eps_q1_ip) for example the o.eps_q1_ip is repeated so many times as in the code block bellow, I think that's because I didn't use the variable `wf_collect=.true.` but it's no longer implemented in Quantum ESPRESSO.

```
total 40364
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 1378528 April  10 11:46 charge-density.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila  241635 April  10 11:46 Cu_ONCV_PBE-1.0.UPF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila   64207 April  10 11:46 data-file-schema.xml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila  207529 April  10 11:46 I_ONCV_PBE-1.0.UPF
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q10_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q11_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q12_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q13_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q14_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q15_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8896 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q16_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    9021 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q1_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q2_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q3_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q4_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q5_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q6_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q7_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q8_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8895 April  10 23:09 o.eel_q9_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q10_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q11_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q12_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q13_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q14_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q15_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8902 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q16_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    9027 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q1_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q2_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q3_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q4_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q5_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q6_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q7_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q8_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8901 April  10 23:09 o.eps_q9_ip
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila   20439 April  10 23:09 r_optics_dipoles_chi
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila   25410 April  10 23:06 r_setup
drwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    8192 April  10 23:07 SAVE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2437340 April  10 11:46 wfc10.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2432588 April  10 11:46 wfc11.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2429816 April  10 11:46 wfc12.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2427836 April  10 11:46 wfc13.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2432192 April  10 11:46 wfc14.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2434964 April  10 11:46 wfc15.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2427836 April  10 11:46 wfc16.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2448824 April  10 11:46 wfc1.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2427440 April  10 11:46 wfc2.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2429816 April  10 11:46 wfc3.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2441300 April  10 11:46 wfc4.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2429420 April  10 11:46 wfc5.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2437736 April  10 11:46 wfc6.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2442884 April  10 11:46 wfc7.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2435360 April  10 11:46 wfc8.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila 2430608 April  10 11:46 wfc9.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 camila camila    1722 April  10 23:06 yambo.in
```

How can I plot the dielectric function real part for example in this case, please?

Comment: +1 But for [**these reasons**](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/5), instead of a screenshot are you able to use the command `ls -l` to list those files in a terminal, and then copy-and-paste the output into a ```code``` block?

Comment: @Camilla could you share your workflow such as input files for scf, nscf, and epsilon calculation? In my case I also didn't use `wf_collect=.true.` but I didn't get that many output files! So I suspect probably the reason is something different.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin I didn't use epsilon from Quantum ESPRESSO I used Yambo code to get that. First I did scf calculation using quantum ESPRESSO then I used Yambo to get the optical properties

Comment: I see. In that case, I cannot help as I am not familiar with Yambo. On a related note, one can calculate optical properties such as dielectric function, jdos, raman etc. using QE only.

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin in k-points do you use always gamma? Have tried to use automatic k-points?

Comment: @Camilla I think that was the case a few version ago. Now you can use automatic k-points. I used automatic k-points with `nosym=.true.` and `noinv=.true.` to disable auto-symmetrization. I use QE 7.2

Comment: Thanks for reformatting the screenshot :)

Answer (score 2):

After I repeated the calculation so many times I figured out that the problem arise if you use k-points {automatic}. When k-points {gamma} is used the problem is fixed and just 1 `o.eps_q1_ip` is generated (same thing for the other outputs)

Comment: I don't think this is necessary to do a gamma point-only calculation. For example, see these [scf](https://github.com/nguyen-group/QE-SSP/blob/master/mos2/optic/scf.in) and [nscf](https://github.com/nguyen-group/QE-SSP/blob/master/mos2/optic/nscf.in) input files using automatic k-points and their [output](https://github.com/nguyen-group/QE-SSP/tree/master/mos2/optic/reference). Could you share your workflow on how you obtained the dielectric function using Yambo so that I can reproduce it?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin But in my case I didnt use `nosym=.true.`  and `noinv=.true.` like you mentionned in the comment above. For the input file I used the same one that I shared before in the chat room